# Use scapy with npcap on Windows

Tags: scapy, npcap

I am using scapy 2.4.5 with Python 3.9.5 on Windows 11. I have npcap version 1.55 install.

I have some Wireshark packet captures that I am trying to use scapy's sniff function on the file and filter out various packets.

However, when I use `filter="udp"` with sniff I get an exception about tcpdump not being available.

Below is the script I am currently trying to use.

```
from scapy.all import *


conf.use_pcap = True

pcap_file_path = r"C:\8OCT21_DDL_00001_20211008214804"

packets = sniff(offline=pcap_file_path, 
                count=10,
                filter="udp")
packets.summary()
```

However I get this exception:

```
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1263, in sniff
    sniffer._run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1072, in _run
    sniff_sockets.update((PcapReader(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 1074, in <genexpr>
    tcpdump(fname,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\scapy\utils.py", line 2095, in tcpdump
    raise Scapy_Exception(
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: tcpdump is not available
```

Any idea on how to use scapy sniff on Windows with npcap instead of tcpdump?

Comment: Looks related to this: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2223. I would post your question there, as the bug may be reappearing. You could also try 2.4.4 where the fix was pushed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not your filter, rather it's the "offline" option in sniff function. You can perform live sniff of packets, or use `rdpcap()` function to first load pcap in RAM, and then do what you want to do.

```
from scapy.all import rdpcap
from scapy.layers.inet import UDP

scapy_cap = rdpcap("responses.pcap")
for pck in PCAP:
    if pck[UDP]:
        print(pck.summary())
```

This is not a solution to why it throws tcpdump exception, but more of a workaround to get something out of your pcap.
Keep in mind that large pcap files will eat RAM like nothing else if you try to load them with `rdpcap()`.